# SSAS MDX. How to create dynamic set from measure value?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I have clients who bought some products:

```
Month    name    SKU
201508   Client1    1
201508   client2    2
201508   client3    3
201508   client4    2
201508   client5    2
201508   client6    3
201508   client7    2
```

I need to count clients on each number of SKU:

```
Month/SKU    1    2    3
201508       1    4    2
```

I found one answer - create fake table. But it would be uncomfortable. Is it possible to create dynamic set based on measure value?

Comment: is SKU a DIM or is it something from Fact? Have you tried an MDX solution? - you've included the tag mdx but I cannot see any...

Comment: SKU  is measure, like number of products. But i didn't find any MDX example that can help me

Comment: So you basically want to get the count of Clients rolled up by the distinct values of SKU for the given month?

Comment: Do you have any dimension where you store the ProductID/ ProductNames, i.e. dim from where the Measure SKU is derived from?

Comment: @SouravA, yes, i want to count clients of each value from SKU. And yes, i have dimension with Products.